# Quartz Scheduler: Schedule job on second last day of month

Tags: java, expression, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need to run a job on the second and/or third last day of a month `(e.g. 30.05.2013, 29.06.2013, 30.07.2013)`.

I know that I can run a job on the last day of month using for example

```
    0 0 9 L * ?
```

What I need is something like

```
    0 0 9 L-1 * ?
```

Is there any **"inbuild" option** for this kind of scheduling that I am missing?

If so, how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
0 15 10 L-2 * ?
```

I think it will help you. For reference use [this quartz's official documents](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) . Here every thing is given in detail.

For verification of next fire time pliase use [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/testing-quartz-cron-expressions.html) link.

Comment: Thanks! I must have somehow skipped this part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for Cronstring (five values)

```
0 0 L-2 * ? # for second last day
```

for Crontab (six values)

```
 0 0 0 L-2 * ?  # for second last day
```